# Questions on invariant tensors and representations of $SU(n)$ and $SO(n)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensors

I'm aware that the invariant/isotropic tensors in $SO(n)$ are $\epsilon^{i_1 i_2 \dots i_n}$ and $\delta^{ij}$. We can use the latter to find the trace of a tensor, Tr$(X)=\delta_{ij}X^{ij}$. Hence, we can decompose a general tensor into the following subspaces: the subspace of symmetric+traceless tensors, the subspace of traces, and that/those of antisymmetric tensors, e.g. for a rank 2 tensor,
$$X^{ij}=\underbrace{X^{(ij)}-\frac{1}{3}\delta^{ij}\text{Tr}X}_\text{symmetric+traceless}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{3}\delta^{ij}\text{Tr}X}_\text{trace}+\underbrace{X^{[ij]}}_\text{antisym.}$$
where $X^{[ij]}\propto\epsilon^{ij}$. Since $\delta^{ij}$ and $\epsilon^{ij}$ are invariant in $SO(n)$, I understand that all these subspaces are invariant.

In $SU(n)$, $\delta^i_j$ is invariant, while $\delta^{ij}$ is no longer invariant, so I assume that while the above decomposition can still be made, it is not particularly useful, as e.g. the trace subspace $\delta^{ij}\text{Tr}(X)$ would no longer be an invariant subspace and would not yield an irreducible representation -- **is this reasoning correct?**

I would also kindly like to ask for some clarification on the following remarks made [here](http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_1_v2.0%20Rotations%20in%203D,%20so(3),%20su(2).pdf) and [here](http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_8_v2.2%20Highest%20weight%20representations.pdf):

> For $SU(n)$, there is in general no rank-2 metric [such as $\delta^{ij}$ in $SO(n)$] that can be used to trace together pairs of fundamental representation indices. Instead, one must contract one fundamental and one conjugate index. The latter turns out to be equivalent to contracting with the rank-$n$ completely antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon^{i_1 i_2 \dots i_n}$.

> There is no natural “metric” for $SU(n+1)$ ($n\geq2$) that can be used to contract pairs
> of defining representation indices to produce an invariant scalar, unlike $SO(n)$.

What does it mean that there is no-rank 2 metric such as $\delta^{ij}$? Is this the statement that $\delta^{ij}$ exists, but is not invariant under $SU(n)$? And if it exists, why can we not use it to lower/raise indices?

What does it mean to contract a fundamental index with a conjugate one? I imagine this means contracting an index that transforms in the fundamental rep with one which transforms in the conjugate rep, but I'm not quite sure how to "visualise" it in the form of an equation, and also why one "must" do this, so any insight here would be really appreciated.

Finally, why is this equivalent to contracting with $\epsilon^{i_1 i_2 \dots i_n}$?

Thanks!